# Zedgraph symbol.fill

Tags: fill, zedgraph

In Zedgraph I am unable to get my circle filled - even though I think I have copied the docs. Anyone know why?

```
myCurve[j] = myPane.AddCurve(SerNames[j], list[j], colours[j], SymbolType.None);
myCurve[j].Line.IsVisible = false;
myCurve[j].Symbol.Type = SymbolType.Circle;
myCurve[j].Symbol.Size = 4.0F;
myCurve[j].Symbol.Border.Width = 2.0F;
myCurve[j].Symbol.Border.Color = Color.Red;
myCurve[1].Symbol.Fill = new Fill(Color.Red);
//myCurve[1].Symbol.Fill.IsVisible = true;
myCurve[1].Symbol.Fill.Type = FillType.Solid;
```

Comment: One time you use myCurve[j] and one time myCurve[1]. That might be the problem :-)

Comment: No that's ddeliberate. I have several curves in this chart

Comment: I agree with SpeziFish. Why are you doing that? And after you changed the symbol etc have you refreshed the graph with `Invalidate()` or `Refresh()`?

Comment: As I said - the one is deliberate - I am targeting a particular line.  Yes - I refresh afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may lie outside the code sample provided. One thing that stands out as odd is that when you add the curve to the pane, you specify `SymbolType.None`, yet two lines later it is set to `SymbolType.Circle`. This should not cause a fill problem, but I would still change the original symbol type to the desired type and eliminate the redundant line.

Next, I presume you have many curves added to the pane, but only want solid circles on `myCurve[1]`. If one of the other curves is in on top of 1, and has data points in the exact same location, those circles will hide the filled ones. You might want to guarantee that `myCurve[1]` is in the foreground, using the [`Move()` method](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/M_ZedGraph_CurveList_Move.htm):

```
myPane.CurveList.Move(myPane.CurveList.IndexOf(myCurve[1]), -999);
```